# Comparing 2 Nearest Neighbors lists in terms of similarity

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining

I have 2 Datasets D and D' where D' is a slightly perturbed version of D. Assume that I have the top K nearest neighbors to a data point P in D say L1 and the corresponding list from D'(the top K nearest neighbors to P in D') say L2. What methods exist to compare the simlarity of L1 and L2.

I am aware of the following methods:

1. Jaccard Similarity -- This seems to be too basic for it does not take into account the fact the actual distances and the fact that the neighborhood is more or less maintained across the 2 data sets except for a few neighbors getting pushed out of the top K even though they might still fairly close.
2. Use metrics proposed in  "Comparing Top K Lists" paper (like the minimizing Kendall Tau). This one seems reasonable but I believe it too generic and once again ignores the distances (focusing only on the rankings)
3. Use a weighted version of the above perhaps using distances as weights.
4. NDCG (used typically for evaluating relevance of search results)

What I am looking for is a distance measure between 2 lists that takes into account the items as well as their actual distances. Is there any literature on this topic or any metrics that I am unaware of. What other techniques are used by researchers in this field  especially if you want to evaluate the stability of nearest neighbor results.

Comment: From the way you have stated the problem, it seems to me that the thing you're evaluating is the quality of D' as an approximation of D, from the point of view of someone who can only run k-nearest-neighbour queries on these datasets.  Is that right?  If so then I believe you specifically ought to disregard the distances, and care about just how much the sets of nearest neighbours differ, which is well measured by the Jaccard index.  It might also make sense to care about the extent to which the rank order of those top k results differs between queries on D and D'.

Comment: Actually I am interested not in whether D is an approximation to D' but am really interested in which points in D have changed in D'. I am for example looking at evolving networks (I have snapshots of a weighted network in 2 different snaphots and now I want to quantify the change in each node by looking at its K nearest neighbors). Hence I believe the distances matter in my case

Comment: I see, yes that makes sense.  It's not a topic I have any expertise on I'm afraid, although I would probably opt for something that generalises the Jaccard index (e.g. so that it would return m/(2k-m) if you applied it to the results of a query whose k nearest neighbours in D were all at distance 1 from P, and for which m <= k of these neighbours were also nearest neighbours of P in D', and also at distance 1 from P there).  Weighting each element by the reciprocal of its distance from P would work, and would have the effect of penalising close neighbours that go missing in D' the hardest.

Comment: OTOH if the actual sets of neighbours are not that important you could of course throw their identities away, and just calculate ordinary descriptive stats on the k raw distances (mean, variance, higher moments etc.)

Comment: Hmm, "its distance" in the above is underspecified...  there are two distances for each element that both D and D' report as a neighbour!  I would use the reciprocal of the max of the two to weight the terms in the numerator (intersection), and the reciprocal of the min to weight the terms in the denominator (union).  This will have the (I would say conservative) effect of reducing the score whenever the distance to P changes (up or down).

Comment: Thanks !.Indeed that seems a reasonable thing to do. I posted this query to see if there are any well established measures than crafting my own but it looks like that is not the case

Comment: You're welcome :)  If you're looking for more definitive answers, possibly with citations etc., you might get a better response on the CS StackExchange website.

Comment: What is NDCG? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Normalized discounted cumulative gain. Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain